# Session lost while on PythonAnywhere Web2Py but NOT locally

Tags: session-variables, web2py, pythonanywhere

I use a session variable to pass some info with a redirect:

```
session.OrigText = XML(str(OrigText))
redirect(URL('SearchResultsOrigText'))
```

It arrives at the new URL / page / view - SearchResultsOrigText  - and works Ok. 
But when from that new URL - SearchResultsOrigText- I navigate away (and it doesn't matter where I go from this new page), when returning with the 'back" button of the browser, the session.OrigText is now empty (showing as 'None').

This behaviour is happening only on PA and not locally.
I do not use session.forget anywhere in my code.

Trying to pass the 'html heavy' content in the OrigText as a dictionary variable (not a session variable) gets me into another interesting issue...Python Anywhere says "Something's wrong 502- Back End". 
(Silent failing ?) This happens on PythonAnywhere but NOT locally as well.
Sanitizing this var doesn't help...

But let's focus on the first question...
Why is the session variable lost after 1.redirect and 2.leaving the new page / view - when hosted on PythonAnywhere and NOT locally ?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more details. The session could be getting cleared or renewed if you are transitioning from logged in to logged out or going from HTTP to HTTPS (and have set `session.secure()` or `request.requires_https()`). Check the browser developer tools and see if the *same* session cookie is being sent back and forth at each request.

Answer (score 1):

Flask sessions, by default use cookies, so it's possible that somewhere in your settings you have a setting for what domain to set the cookies on and that is not set correctly. It's also possible that you haven't set a secret key for sessions.

Comment: It is Web2Py on PythonAnywhere - NOT Flask. And I've noticed bug doesn't appear always: sometimes the session variable is lost and sometimes it is not: on the same network.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem recently in PythonAnywhere. I solved it by deleting my domain's cookies from Firefox. I still don't know how they were messed up, though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no "session.forget(response)" in your code or framework code along the way.

Comment: I didn't use session.forget anywhere in my code. Is it possible this is used by Web2Py or PythonAnywhere behind the scenes ?

Comment: I would dump the session vars to a log and then set the datetime in the session afterwards so you see the last value set on each hit.  Also maybe something with browser cache settings local vs network?  Just some thoughts.